es una pregunta de url de 1 pagina web hecha con html
como le pongo una url simple con javascript a la pagina web hecha con html , url simple me refiero a : https://www.elnombredelapaginaweb.com
y no a esas : https://d.WE/gkjkdudn.fdhy etc. etc. y una url super larga.
el otro dia me la respondieron pero no alcance a anotarla completa.si esta la persona que la respondio se la pediria denuevo porfavor.
gracias

Si te respondieron una pregunta, esta en el sitio.. y seguro en tu historial de navegacion tambien...

Si mal no recuerdo, esa pregunta fue cerrada porque no explicaste cuál es el caso de uso que estás teniendo. De hecho, ¿qué estás queriendo hacer?

Efectivamente...

es una pregunta simple :

es una pregunta simple :   como le pongo www.nombredemipaginaweb.com
a mi pagina web?

Pues tenes que registrar el dominio y luego apuntarlo al servidor donde tengas alojada tu pagina... usualmente donde contrates el servicio tiene un tuto de como hacerlo...

Esto no se pone con js ni con html ni con nada.. lo da donde contrates el nombre

Es una pregunta simple. con una respuesta simple que aparentemente no quieres entender o no te gusta. Es así y punto. No vas a obtener una respuesta diferente a menos que preguntes algo difrente.
